# What are risks of setting EF 4.5 EDMX "Validate on Build" to "False"?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmx, edmx-designer

In order to dramatically improve build times on developer machines and the build server, I'm considering setting the EF 4.5 entity model's "Validate on Build" property to "False".

What are the risks of this approach?

For purposes of this question:

- The development team has server-based build process
- Development is active on multiple branches and changes are merged to a common branch for release
- Any developer merging to/from a branch would be expected to open the EDMX before check-in so VS will validate the merged model